# How do I integrate push notifications for a wordpress api/IOS mobile app?

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress

I have a wordpress/Woocommerce site that we are taking the data via rest api and creating a Native ios app. We are trying to figure out how to integrate push notifications into the app. Is there a wordpress plugin or is there another solution that allows us to integrate push notifications?

I have looked at some wordpress plugins for push notifications but it seems to just be for a website/browser.

(*This is an IOS app using Wordpress API as the backend)

Comment: are you creating native app from Wordpress or you have just a website?

Comment: Creating a native ios app from wordpress

Comment: how? can you give any details? how it supposed to work? you have backend that will send notifications?

Comment: Using wordpress rest api. Have you ever heard of this? Not sure how to do the backend for notifications this is what I am asking about. I am trying to figure out how to do integrate push notifications with the way I am setting up this app from wordpress api
https://scottbolinger.com/woocommerce-rest-api-mobile-app/

Comment: ok, that is clear now, you phrased it like you were making iOS app on Wordpress not a BACKEND for app

Comment: Ah gotcha... Sorry for the confusion I added a note or clarification.. Any suggestions/help?

Comment: I was doing something like this only once but remember reading about it here: https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-push-notifications/

Comment: Take a look at this link if it helps: https://products.delitestudio.com/wordpress/push-notifications-for-wordpress/